# How to declare variables for Win32 APIs?

Tags: excel, vba, winapi

I'd like a **general guide** for how to write VBA declare statements for using arbitrary Win32 APIs. Not a list of declare statements for some selection of Win32 APIs (which probably doesn't include the API I'm looking for now or the one I'll be looking for six months from now).

A general guide would educate me on how different C / Win32 data types should be handled. For both 32-bit or 64-bit Office.

This topic on [adapting VBA for 64-bit Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Concepts/Getting-Started/64-bit-visual-basic-for-applications-overview) tells me I can use LongPtr and that Office 32-bit or 64-bit will adapt that as appropriate. That's only useful if I know when a Long was needed for 32-bit.

[This VB.Net topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/bc30828) says 'As Any' isn't supported but that's VB.Net, not VBA.  I gather that 'As Any' is appropriate for VBA but when do I use it? For APIs that take VOID or pVOID or LPVOID?

As a specific example, I need to adapt this declare:

```
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (pDest As Any, pSrc As Any, ByVal ByteLen As Long)
```

Per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa366535(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), the last parameter is SIZE_T:

```
void CopyMemory(
_In_       PVOID  Destination,
_In_ const VOID   *Source,
_In_       SIZE_T Length
);
```

I've seen some adaptations for 64-bit Office leave this in the declare as `ByVal ... As Long` but others change it to `LongPtr`. What is correct?

I don't want to hang on a kernel call gone bad.

Is there a general guide to figure out how any Win32 API should be handled?

Comment: I am afraid you cannot 'build' API functions according to some rules. You must use them as they are documented and take only care of the data type to be supplied for its parameters. Not only 'SafePtr' is changed in API for 64 bit... There are functions accepting parameters `As Any`, but this is strictly related to that specific parameters and the way the API use it. In order to understand basics of API, I would recommend you looking [here](https://riptutorial.com/vba/topic/10569/api-calls). And also follow "API Calls Related Examples" from the page bottom side, study examples and their links.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only ultimate solution is really to understand types in C / C++ => learn a good part of  these languages, but also learn some good part on Windows types (.h, macros, etc. sometimes, you have to dig into SDK header files). For example SIZE_T is a Windows-defined C macro (somewhat different than C's size_t) => ULONG_PTR (another macro) => `unsigned long` (32-bit in x86) or `__int64` (64-bit in x64). Once you have the language-independent binary representation, find an equivalent ("blittable") binary representation. for VBA, it should be LongPtr (same size as process bitness).

Comment: I understand the basics of APIs. Just not completely on top of marshalling of types across COM to flat C, etc. I'm not trying to "build" API functions; those are defined in the Win32 header files. I'm trying to learn how to write VBA declare statements so I can call them. I had seen the site you pointed at, but the examples were hit and miss. But I just noticed [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9970), which is definitely helpful.

Comment: @SimonMourier: Thanks. I just started a dummy C++ project in VS with #include <Windows.h> so that I could follow back the def'n trail for SIZE_T to confirm it's 64-bit. But other things are less obvious. E.g., on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee691831(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) it says to use StrPtr "to return pointers to strings", but the same page has examples of string out params ByVal As String. Just not clear.

Comment: Think about what I said earlier, think "binary". `ByVal As String` "blittable language independent type" is a pointer (what else could it be). `StrPtr` is a function that returns a pointer. So you can define the Declare as `ByVal As String` and pass a string, or `ByVal As LongPtr` and pass `StrPtr(string)`. Key point to remember: there is usually more than one way of defining the same function. Pick the one you prefer.

Comment: OK, I still need to unpack some things in my mind, but that was informative!

Comment: I have an Excel VBA project that I worked on years ago but continue to use on occasion, that parses binary font files and writes info into worksheets. Writing was the slow part, and I had tried to speed it up by writing info to memory, putting on the clipboard and then pasting. I ended up with CopyMemory in several places. Now, converting to 64 bit, and the copy/paste stuff is causing crashes. I need to debug that.

Comment: In such a situation, when need specific help for a specific piece of code, please edit your question and ask specifically about your problem, showing the line where your code crashes... You will better learn by doing and correcting mistakes. If you receive some help, the same learning process will take place, I would dare to suggest...

Comment: @SimonMourier It's unfortunate that you picked `String` specifically to make your point because it doesn't actually work for `String` specifically. With `ByVal As String` the API will receive a `LPSTR`, with `ByVal As LongPtr` and `StrPtr()` - an `LPWSTR`.

Comment: @GSerg - you're right, my VB is a little bit rusty, I always forget VB/VBA passes ansi string externally, although it stores them as unicode internally (as BSTR). It's awkward but was made like that for compat reasons back then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a general guide for how to write VBA declare statements for using arbitrary Win32 APIs.

This is how I do it.

I go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types and find the data type I need (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>).
If it's defined in the terms of another type from the same page, I look up that too (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>), until I arrive at a basic type.
Then I use the appropriately sized type from VB. `int` is `Long`, `short` is `Integer`, `char*` is `String`, `wchar_t*` is `LongPtr` where you need to pass `StrPtr`, `void*` is `LongPtr`.

> I gather that 'As Any' is still appropriate for VBA. But when do I use it? For APIs that take VOID? Or pVOID? or LPVOID?

`As Any` is helpful when

- You don't want to declare the actual type it receives (e.g. it's a complex structure, the parameter is optional, and you are not using it)
- There can be multiple different things that can be passed there and you want to be passing them all at different points

Otherwise it's always possible, safe and correct to redeclare `As Any` using the actual type specified in the API header. Often it's a pointer, which is `ByVal LongPtr`.

Keeping `As Any` puts more responsibility on the caller, but gives them more flexibility. Redeclaring `As Any` as an actual type removes the danger at the cost of said flexibility.

`CopyMemory` is a very fine example of this principle.
The declaration of `pDest As Any, pSrc As Any` is most flexible, and can be used as:

```vb
Dim a As Long, b As Long

CopyMemory a, b, ...                             ' Copying from variable b to a (a = b)
CopyMemory ByVal VarPtr(a), ByVal VarPtr(b), ... ' Same
```

```vb
Dim a As LongPtr, b As LongPtr

CopyMemory ByVal a, ByVal b, ...   ' Copying from memory pointed to by b to memory pointed to by a
```

which is flexible, but if you misuse it:

```vb
Dim a As Long, b As Long

CopyMemory ByVal a, ByVal b, ...  ' Wrong: passing values as pointers; likely memory access violation
CopyMemory VarPtr(a), VarPtr(b), ... ' Wrong: passing pointers to pointers;
                                     ' Overwrites the temporary storage VB provides
                                     ' No crash, but no meaningful copying either
```

```vb
Dim a As LongPtr, b As LongPtr

CopyMemory a, b, ...              ' Likely wrong: copying the pointer value of b into a (a = b)
```

you can crash and/or corrupt the data.

Having declared the same parameters as `ByVal pDest As LongPtr, ByVal pSrc As LongPtr`, you lose the ability to pass `Long`s ByRef like in the first example and will need to explicitly use `VarPtr` each time, but you won't need to think too much how to call the function. There is still some danger though, because you can still call it as `CopyMemory a, b` with `Long` parameters, and it will crash for passing values as pointers, but at least you will see from the function definition what you are passing something wrong, while `As Any` doesn't give you a hint.

Comment: This is helpful, and along the lines of "teach to fish" guidance I was looking for.